# Android studio- Emulator wont work

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to run an emulator to test hello world app on andro studio but when I try to run emulator by hardware rendering it always crashes BTW I have installed haxm,enabled vt,nx. so my only choice was to use software render but when I tried it the emu was stuck on the Android logo I have waited 2-3 hours but it won't change...any ideas how to use hardware rendering?

Comment: Do you see any error messages when trying to run?

Comment: ya its a crash report

"it appears your computer openGl graphics drive crashed.This was probably caused by a bug in your app's opengl code (I'm trying to run a simple hello world). You should check your manufacturer website for an updated graphic driver. You can also tell your emulator to use software rendering for this device" also I want to know what opengl version does emulating require?